# MySQL Foreign Key format during table creation

Tags: mysql

I've run into a strange situation. I have two tables that initially looked like this:

```
CREATE TABLE vendors (

    vendor_id   INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    [...]
    created_at  TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at  DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

    PRIMARY KEY (vendor_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET=utf8mb4;

CREATE TABLE vendor_orders (

    vendor_order_id  INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    vendor_id        INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL REFERENCES vendors(vendor_id),
    [...]
    created_at       TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at       DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

    PRIMARY KEY (vendor_order_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET=utf8mb4;
```

However, after inspecting the database, I discovered the foreign key in the table definition for vendor_orders wasn't created. I then tried to create the second table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE vendor_orders (

    vendor_order_id  INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    vendor_id        INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    [...]
    created_at       TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    updated_at       DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

    PRIMARY KEY (vendor_order_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (vendor_id) REFERENCES vendors(vendor_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET=utf8mb4;
```

That worked, and my foreign key was created. Can anyone tell me what the difference between the two formats is? I thought both were supposed to be equivalent. I'm using MySQL 5.6.33.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expectation was correct, the references keyword as you used in the first example should create the `foreign key`, but it does not work that way. You are not the first who ran into this [MySQL bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=4919). The solution is to avoid using the inline `foreign key` definition and explicitly write out the `foreign key` as you did in the second example.

Comment: Huh, well that's profoundly annoying. Thank you for the answer, because this was driving me crazy.

Comment: @Crankycyclops I absolutely agree with you that this is annoying, I had the same frustration as you had now when I tried to do the same with the very same approach.